# React js function calling from external file

Tags: reactjs

i want to use a external .js file where all the system library or function resides. For instance file name sysFunction.js

```
import React from 'react';
function currYear() {
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
 return year;
 }
```

now the file where i am calling this function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';`
import Logo from "../../../assets/app/media/img//logos/logo-1.png";
import sysFunction from "../SysFunctions/SysFunction";
export default class Login extends Component {
    render(){
       return({currYear()});
    }
}
```

my function actually resides in a another file which is normally not a component file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
    import React from 'react';
    export function currYear() {
       var year = new Date().getFullYear();
        return year;
     }

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom';`
    import Logo from "../../../assets/app/media/img//logos/logo-1.png";
    import { currYear } from "../SysFunctions/SysFunction";
    export default class Login extends Component
      {
       render(){
          return({currYear()}
       );
      }
    }
```